# Issues with retrieving information from a class module for output within a switch statement

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement

I know this may be something obvious to some with experience but I am in the middle of my first real class for C++ programming. I have come across something in my code that I have been trying to resolve without any success. I am trying to extract the sum of the total value of "m_cost" stored within a array that is inside of these class modules. I want to output the total value inside of a switch statement for print out. Just seeing if someone can point me in the right direction or if I have completely gone off-track with the logic.

Project Code section in question:

```
void materialsMenu()
{
  Inventory record[MAX_REC];
  int i, n;

  cout << "\n=====Inventory Management=====\n";
  cout << "\nHow many Materials are there to be used? : ";
  cin >> n;

  cout << "Enter " << n << " Materials\n";
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    record[i].getdata();

  cout << "\n\n---Material Information---\n";
  cout << "\n" << setw(8) << "Item Name  "
      << setw(10) << " Price per foot "
      << setw(19) << " Cost " << endl;
  cout << endl << "-------------------------------------------" << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    record[i].showdata();
}

void Inventory::getdata() {
  cout << endl;
  cout << "\nEnter Material Name : ";
  cin >> itemName;
  cout << "Enter Price Per Foot : ";
  cin >> ppf;
  cout << "Enter Total Length Needed in Feet (ft) : ";
  cin >> length;
  cout << endl;

  m_cost = ppf*length;
  m_costT=???????? **this is the issue** 
}
```

Materials.H file contents:

```
#ifndef MATERIALS_H

using namespace std;

class Materials {
private:
 char itemName[15];
 float ppf;
 float length;
 double m_cost;
 float m_costT;


public:
Materials()
{
    ppf = 0;
    length = 0;
    m_cost = 0;
    m_costT = 0;


}
Materials(int itemName, float ppf, float length, double m_cost, float 
m_costT)
{
    length = getLength();
    ppf = getPpf();
    m_cost = getCost();
    m_costT = getTotal();

}

float getLength()
{
    return length;
}
float getPpf()
{
    return ppf;
}
double getCost()
{
    return m_cost;
}
float getTotal()
{
    return m_costT;
}
void getdata();
void showdata();

};
#endif // !MATERIALS_H
```

Comment: Is really all that irrelevant code necessary to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: I wasn't sure where my problem was, just trying to put everything into scope.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your code, *watching* values of variables and execution flow.  Often, using a debugger is faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect your code or debug it for you.  Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have edited my initial question and code. It isn't a debugger issue, I just can't figure out my next step to resolve this and its driving me crazy that I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: Unfortunately, your edit was too severe and has removed some information about your class and such, making it very hard to see what is wrong.  AS it is not, I do not know what `m_costT` is supposed to be calculating.

Comment: If the issue is that each "Record" has its own Total variable that is supposed to contain the total of the whole array of records, then I would say that this variable is in the wrong location as it cannot properly access all the other values in the record array.  You may need another class to contain those records and have the total live in that class.  Then, you can just for loop through the records and add each to this total var.

Comment: Inside a function belonging to a specific `Inventory` object is probably not a good place to do something with an array of `Inventory` objects that belongs to a different function.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan 'm_costT' is what I was designating as a total sum of the 'm_cost' outputs from the array 'record' input.

Comment: Then, it doesn't belong in the record class as I stated above.  The record class should have no idea about any other record class's data.  Instead, it needs to be, as I stated, in a super class that contains the records array and then the cost needs to have a getter or some method of communicating to this external/super class its cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider something like this to hold your records.  It's very simple, but it demonstrates the idea of one class holding another and shows information hiding and all sorts of other tidbits.  You are struggling to get that total because the Record class shouldn't care about this.  The total is a concept outside of the scope of a Record.  And as such, it is very difficult to calculate this from where you wanted to do it.  (Though it is possible, it breaks all sorts of C++ rules and should be avoided)

Example:

```
class Record;

class RecordHolder
{
public:
    int GetTotal() 
    {
        int retVal = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)  // Magic number 10 for demo purposes only...
        {
            retVal += records[i].m_cost;  // Or use a public get function.
        }
        return retVal;
    }

private:
    Record records[10];  // Magic number 10 for demo purposes only...
};
```

The RecordHolder could also do printing, add/removing records, etc.  It controls the records array.  The Records are just Records and don't care about such management.

Comment: Thank you, I was wandering if I bit off more than I could chew with doing class type data structures at this point in time or if I should just delete and re-make in just "for" and array statements for individual items in the sub-structure of the switch statement.

Comment: I don't think what I gave you here, nor what you created is too big a bite.  It's more data organization in a C++ style.  In the future, when you run into issues where your data just isn't available to you in the way you want, take a step back and see if there may be a better way to organize your data.  Organizing the data in the proper manner makes coding go so much easier - and makes it easier to maintain.